# Can I share data between different class instances in Python?

Tags: python, oop, static

I have a class `option`, for which I create an instance `z`.

How can I use the `optionbook` from instance `z` in another instance of `option`, say `y`?

```
class option(object):
    nextIdNum = 0 
    def __init__(self):
          self.optionbook = {}
          self.options = []
          self.optioncomb = {}
    def addopttobook(self,optiondescription):
        self.idNum = option.nextIdNum
        if optiondescription in self.optionbook.values() :
            raise ValueError('Duplicate Option')
        self.optionbook["Opt.ID." + str(self.idNum)] = optiondescription 
        option.nextIdNum += 1
    def addoptocomb (self,option):
         combID = 0  
         if option in self.optionbook.values():
               if option in self.options:
                    raise ValueError('Duplicate Option')
               self.combID = combID
               self.options.append(str(list(self.optionbook.keys())[list(self.optionbook.values()).index(option)]) +":"+ option)
               self.optioncomb["Optcomb.ID." + str(self.combID)] = self.options
               self.combID +=1  
         else: 
              raise ValueError('Add options to optionbook first')
    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.optionbook)

    def getOptionbook(self):
        return self.optionbook.copy()

    def getOptioncomb(self):

        return self.optioncomb.copy()


z = option()
z.addopttobook('open the well')

y = option()
y.addoptocomb('open the well')
```

This gives me a `ValueError "Add options to optionbook first"` , I understand the error, `y` and `z` are different instances. I just want to know how to share data between different instances of same class.

Comment: Maybe you could use static data of class, but you should really trim your code to a [mcve] to get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already defined a variable, that 'shares data between different instance': `nextIdNum`, so you can do the same for `optionbook`.

```
class option(object):
    nextIdNum = 0
    optionbook = {}

    def __init__(self):
          self.options = []
          self.optioncomb = {}
    ...  # rest of your code here

z = option()
z.addopttobook('z opens the well 1')
z.addopttobook('z opens the well 2')

y = option()
z.addopttobook('y opens the well 1')
y.addoptocomb('z opens the well 1')

print(option.optionbook)
print (option.optionbook == z.optionbook == y.optionbook)
```

Returns:

```
{'Opt.ID.0': 'z opens the well 1', 'Opt.ID.1': 'z opens the well 2', 'Opt.ID.2': 'y opens the well 1'}
True  # >> The class itself as well as all instances share the same data.
```

Comment: thank you , as a beginer, this trick is of coure very important and interesting to know !

Answer (score 0):

You need a static variable in the `option` class, and extend your methods to be able to pass in a variable for which `optionbook` to use:

```
class option(object):
    nextIdNum = 0
    optionbook = {} # this variable is "static", i.e. not bound to an instance, but the class itself

    def __init__(self):
          self.optionbook = {}
          self.options = []
          self.optioncomb = {}

    def addopttobook(self,optiondescription, book): # add book-param
        self.idNum = option.nextIdNum
        if optiondescription in self.optionbook.values() :
            raise ValueError('Duplicate Option')
        book["Opt.ID." + str(self.idNum)] = optiondescription 
        option.nextIdNum += 1

    def addoptocomb (self,option, book): # add book-param
         combID = 0  
         if option in book.values():
               if option in self.options:
                    raise ValueError('Duplicate Option')
               self.combID = combID
               self.options.append(str(list(book.keys())[list(book.values()).index(option)]) +":"+ option)
               self.optioncomb["Optcomb.ID." + str(self.combID)] = self.options
               self.combID +=1  
         else: 
              raise ValueError('Add options to optionbook first')

    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.optionbook)

    def getOptionbook(self):
        return self.optionbook.copy()

    def getOptioncomb(self):
        return self.optioncomb.copy()
```

That way, you can access the static member `optionbook` via `option.optionbook`:

```
z = option()
# you can always access the static member by referencing it via the class-name
# it is not bound to any concrete instances
z.addopttobook('open the well', option.optionbook) 
y = option()
y.addoptocomb('open the well', option.optionbook)
print(option.optionbook)
```

Comment: thanks you !   This works perfectly for my purpose !