# How can I use the data in other object within the same class?

Tags: python, class, object

Let's say I have two objects `Cell_i-1` and `Cell_i`

There are some data in each cell which are n, N, Q, alpha, S, R, and y

However, some value of the present cell `Cell_i` requires the value of data in the previous cell `Cell_i-1`, such as

`alpha_i = 1 if n_i-1 <= Q_i`

`aplha_i = 5 if n_i-1 > Q_i`

`y_i = min {S_i-1 , R_i}`

How can I use the value in the previous cell to compute the values of data in the present cell?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import array as arr

class cell:

    def __init__ (self, qmax ,n ,N , delta_t = 0.2 ,delta_l = 0.5 ):
        self.qmax = qmax
        self.Q = self.qmax * delta_t
        self.n = n
        self.N = N
        self.alpha = []
        self.S = []
        self.R = []
        self.y = []


    def current (self):
        x = np.minimum(self.Q , self.n)
        self.S.append(x)
        print(self.S)

    def update (self)
```

Comment: Maybe the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333786/can-i-share-data-between-different-class-instances-in-python) can be useful.

Comment: Why don't you pass the other instance of `cell` to a method? I would suggest using more meaningful names for your variables (unless they are meaningful in the specific context/use case). Class names [should be capitalized](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)

Comment: Thank you for your comment and I would like to know how can I  pass the other instance of cell to a method? Since I am just about to learn Python, I don't really know how actually do about it.